# geom_histogram with proportions and factor data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to consistently plot histograms for zonal statistics from a thematic map. The data within a single zone often looks something like this:

```
dat <- data.frame("CLASS" = sample(LETTERS[1:6], 250, replace = TRUE,
                               prob = c(.15, .06, .35, .4, .02, 0)))
dat$CLASS <- factor(dat$CLASS, levels = LETTERS[1:6], ordered = T)
```

wherein not all possible classes may have been present in the zone.

I can pre-compute the data summary and use `geom_bar` and a manual colour scale to get consistent bar colours regardless of missing data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

dat_summ <- dat %>%
  group_by(CLASS, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  summarise(percentage = n() / nrow(.) * 100)

mancols <- viridis_pal()(6)
names(mancols) <- LETTERS[1:6]

ggplot(dat_summ) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = CLASS, y = percentage, fill = CLASS), 
           stat = 'identity', show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mancols, drop = FALSE) +
  labs(x = 'Class', y = 'Percent') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image: geom_bar plot]

But I can't keep the colours consistent across plots when I try to use `geom_histogram`:

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = CLASS,  
                 y = (..count../sum(..count..)) * 100,
                 fill = ..x..), stat = 'count', show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  labs(x = 'Class', y = 'Percent') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

If any of the outside-edge columns (A, F) are count = 0, the colours rescale to where data is present. This doesn't happen if there's a gap in one of the middle classes. Using `scale_fill_viridis_b()` doesn't solve the problem - it always rescales the palette against the number of non-0 columns.

Is it possible to prevent this behaviour and output consistent colours no matter which columns are count = 0, or am I stuck with my `geom_bar` approach?

Comment: Which do you want to use colours, according to ratio or class ?

Comment: each class should always be the same colour regardless of bar height or how many other classes appear on the plot.

Comment: I think this question is about too many things. Is the proportions aspect of the plot really important to this issue? If not, this question should be re-written to leave that out so that people trying to figure out about plotting proportions don’t show up here. I propose changing the title to “Don’t drop factor levels in discrete fill color scale in ggplot2”. Objections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe `scale_fill_discrete/scale_fill_viridis_d(drop = F)` is what you want (with `fill = CLASS`).

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = CLASS,  
                     y = (..count../sum(..count..)) * 100,
                     fill = CLASS), stat = 'count', show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(drop = FALSE) +
  labs(x = 'Class', y = 'Percent') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: aw dang, I knew it would be something simple. That's it - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that you pass the calculated variable `..x..` to `fill` in the aesthetics. It appears the length of this variable  changes with your data set. You could replace it with `scale_fill_manual` and you will get the same plot colours regardless of how many levels there are in your CLASS variable:

```
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = CLASS, y = stat(count/sum(count) * 100), fill = CLASS), stat = 'count', show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FF0000FF", "#CCFF00FF", "#00FF66FF", "#0066FFFF", "#CC00FFFF", "#FF99FFFF")) 
  labs(x = 'Class', y = 'Percent') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Comment: Yep that's it - very close to the accepted answer but avoiding a manual scale gives me more flexibility across different datasets. Thanks though :)